# Embedding html content to <svg> without <foreignObject>

Tags: html, svg

Is it possible to embed html objects to svg element, ie. `<rect>` without using `<foreignObject>`? Is this possible to for example using svg script?

Comment: You'd just have to create a foreignObject tag in javascript. Is that what you want. foreignObject is the only way to display html inside svg elements.

Answer (score 0):

foreignObject seems to be the only way to do that, one way would be to use an Absolutely positioned Div over your rect element